# How to use global filters with 'webmethod' end points?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have some existing code which defines API endpoints using the 'webmethod' decorator like this .

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public static Person GetPerson(string userId)
{
    //... processing
}
```

I would like to define a filter in Global.asax.cs to capture all requests to this set of end points.

I have added this to Global.asx.cs ...

```
public sealed class Foo : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string bar { get; set; }

    public TokenValidationForNonAdminAttribute(string s)
    {
        this.bar = s;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Foo.OnActionExecuting");
    }
}
```

but when I make a request to the `webmethod` endpoint the `OnActionExecuting` doesn't get executed.

Anyone know why that isn't working ?

Comment: MVC Filters are used for MVC Controller because Controllers have Actions associated with them. WebForms do not have this. So MVC filters are useless in ASP.NET WebForms application.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - thanks for your comment, I appreciate it. Do you know of any other way in which all requests to 'webmethod' end points might be trapped ?

Comment: What you want to do by using the Filter? You want to authorize the user or something?

Comment: I want to look for a custom header set by the client.